# Is it possible to mimic the client of a https web service

Tags: https, hacking, wireshark

There is such a windows application that communications with the server through https protocol, it is an auction tool and works only several hours per month. I have captured network packets (by windows network monitor) during one auction.

I am wondering whether it is possible to mimic this client, by analyzing the the packets I collected (or any packets I could collect in future auctions). I know from this wireshark artical "[Secure Socket Layer (SSL)](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL)" that it should be possible (and without much effort) to descypt the entrypted messages from server, **but how? And is it possible to dectrypt the messages sent by client to server, too?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all these things are possible provided that you can ignore/bypass/trick client side authentication if any.  CURL provides the ability to script to do the mimicking, and there is even a [Windows version](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/) available.

If you need to intercept a session, you might try [SSLSniff](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslsniff/).

If you can provide further details we might be able to help a bit more - for example is this a public site which anyone can use?   Does it require the client present a cert to the server ?